# disable browser button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to remove previously visited url from history in asp.net so that if user click on back button of browser user will not go in previous url.

Is there any other method than Window.history.forward()?
Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do this? curious...

Comment: I second teknolagi's question. Having a need for this type of thing is usually a symptom of a different problem which is likely easier to address... like an extra postback polluting your history.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do it is to keep track on the server side of /where/ the user should be, and, if they're backing up (determined from the request uri) push them forward again (location: referrer).